# WPF animated GIF Source change on runtime .. but remains static on source change

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation

Hi guys please help with this ...
What exactly i am trying to do is .. changing the ANIMATED GIF IMAGE SOURCE on runtime.
However the image change is happening but as the image is animated its getting blacked out somehow may be the thread is busy !

Here's the code !

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(@"/BackgroundWorkerWpf;component/Media/p1.gif", UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
```

The image source is changed as per required but the image remains static just like its a snap of the original GIF Image.THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

PS : I AM USING THE REFERENCE LIB FROM [CODEPLEX](http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you changed property animated source you should invoke `ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior` method.

Try following code:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(@"/BackgroundWorkerWpf;component/Media/p1.gif", UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(img, new RepeatBehavior(0));
ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(img, RepeatBehavior.Forever);
```

Comment: This works fine for SECOND(ie. at runtime) time ... but when i change the source again for THIRD time it freezes again or remains static and to be specific i used the repeatbehavior for third source change too..

Comment: @IteratioN07 Bit of a late reply here, but I came across this question while having the same problem today. The solution I came to was to change the repeat behaviour away and back to "Forever" when changing the source later - so `SetRepeatBehaviour(img, new RepeatBehaviour(0))` followed by `SetRepeatBehaviour(img, RepeatBehaviour.Forever)`

Comment: hey I've used the above method and it doesn't work for me, I wonder why.          `var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.UriSource = new Uri(@"Assets/gif-load.gif", UriKind.Relative);
                image.EndInit();
                ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(imgInternet, image);
                ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(imgInternet, new RepeatBehavior(0));
                ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(imgInternet, RepeatBehavior.Forever);`

Comment: While it works well when i set the source in the XAML.       `<Image x:Name="imgInternet" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Assets/gif-load.gif"  Width="35"    Height="35" Margin="10,0,5,0"  />`

Comment: I am using the same code but `.gif` image is showing as static image and animation is not showing

Comment: @sohaiby check out this project: https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif

Comment: @kmatyaszek Thank you. Tell you what, this is the solution which I ultimately implemented in my project :)